# How can i save all push notification locally using SharedPreference Flutter..?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, sharedpreferences

I want to save all push notification which will be send from Firebase and Display all notification in app.

i have tried this but all notification does not save..

**This is my Notification Model**

```
class NotificationModel extends Equatable {   final String title;   final String body;

  const NotificationModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.body,   });

  NotificationModel copyWith({
    String? title,
    String? body,   }) {
    return NotificationModel(
      title: title ?? this.title,
      body: body ?? this.body,
    );   }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'title': title,
      'body': body,
    };   }

  factory NotificationModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return NotificationModel(
      title: map['title'] as String,
      body: map['body'] as String,
    );   }}
```

**and i declare a list of Notification List notificationList = [];**

**save title and body**

```
void saveNotification(String title, String body) async {
    NotificationModel notification =
        NotificationModel(title: title, body: body);

    String jsonData = jsonEncode(notification);

    sharedPreferences.setString('notification', jsonData);

    print('SavedNotification: $jsonData');   }
```

**getting data from this method..**

```
void initializeData() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    //final result = sharedPreferences.getString('notification');

    final result =
        await json.decode(sharedPreferences.getString('notification')!);
    print('type: ${result.runtimeType}');

    NotificationModel model = NotificationModel.fromJson(result);
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      notificationList
          .add(NotificationModel(title: title ?? '', body: description ?? ''));
      title = model.title;
      description = model.body;
    }
  }



FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (event) {
        RemoteNotification? notification = event.notification;
        AndroidNotification? android = event.notification!.android;

        if (notification != null && android != null) {
          _localNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
                  channelDescription: channel.description,
                  icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
            ),
          );
        }
        saveNotification(notification.title!, notification.body!);
        print('SaveData success');
        // print('Saved Data: ${sharedPreferences.getString('title')}');
      },
```

Every time i got just latest title and body...

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the last notification JSON data with the most recent notification data in the 'notification' shared preference key. You should store a `list of JSON <NotificationModel> JSON strings` in `notification` shared preference.

For that update your `saveNotification()` method. you are storing only single **`NotificationModel`** instead of this add that model in List< NotificationModel> and then store this updated notification list JSON.

**Note:**

> In `saveNotification()`, also you need to get first old notification list which is previous stored.
> data from shared preference and add new notification & save that
> updated list.